Properly remove files that are installed but not shipped in any package
Issue
Yocto recipes install files in the do_install task and later packages them in do_package. This is often automated using using inherit [c]make, so bitbake will look for a Makefile or CMakeLists.txt in the source folder (S). If the make files install packages that the recipe does not use in do_package we get a:
ERROR: SOME_RECIPE do_package: QA Issue: SOME_RECIPE: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
/some/file.a
/some/file.service
...

Question
Normally, the solution is adding the files to FILES:{PN} variable, so they will be packaged, thus available on the system.
I want to remove the files instead, because the CmakeLists.txt file in my recipe has install() directives for files I do not wish to package.

Is there a specific Yocto concept for this situation?
If not: which work around is the most maintainable?

Possible solutions / work arounds

Patch CmakeLists.txt and remove the offending install()s -> Maintenance effort once upstream CMakeLists.txt changes
Use Cmake options to disable installing specific targets -> Cmake specific. This answer seems close, but still requires patching.
Create a new package that I do not install in my image -> Not sure if readable for my case, but many recipes like avahi do it this way.
Run rm in do_install:append -> Didn't find a way without hard-coded paths. Also, me manually editing tasks is an additional effort for future maintainers (me probably) that's often preventable.

Yocto recommends option 4. in the error message:
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
However, most meta-oe recipes are instead adding multiple packages, like option 3. Probably, because they want them installable. I think this is more readable, but allows someone to install the other packages, which is should best be prevented in my case.
MWE
I found it quite challenging to create an MWE for this. This one works by misusing cmake.bblass producing this error, when adding another main.c in SRC_URI. Maybe there's a better way.  File contents are below, don't forget the ln -s main.c main2.c. Use bitbake mwe-so to reproduce the error.
recipes-core/mwe-so/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main2.c -> main.c
├── main.c
└── mwe-so.bb

// main.c
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}

# CmakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
add_executable(mwe main.c)
install(TARGETS mwe DESTINATION /usr/local/bin/main123)

# bitbake recipe
SUMMARY = "mwe stackoverflow"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI += "file://CMakeLists.txt"
SRC_URI += "file://main.c"
SRC_URI += "file://main2.c"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit cmake pkgconfig

